# How to run, on a mac, basic AJAX program consisting of JS, php and html files

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xampp

I'm trying to run this AJAX program that I learned from a newboston youtube tutorial.

http://tnbforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=122&t=41868&hilit=ajax

I have a php file, an html file and a javascript file. I have XAMPP installed and the apache server up and running.

Can someone please explain to me the concept of what I need to do in order to get the program to run? I have the 3 files of code all saved to the htdocs folder in XAMPP directory. So now all I do is run localhost along with the appropriate directory pathname to the php file in the browser?

Since the 3 files are saved in the htdocs folder in a subfolder titled "foodstore", with the php file specifically titled "foodstore.php"...  I typed into the browser "localhost/foodstore/foodstore.php"

But the result I get is:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document     tree is shown below.
<response>
<br/>
<b>Notice</b>
: Undefined index: food in
<b>
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/foodstore/foodstore.php
</b>
on line
<b>6</b>
<br/>
Enter a food you idiot
</response>
```

What exactly do I not need to do with the JS file and the HTML file? And does that play a role in why this isn't working?

I know this is a simple concept with a simple solution, but obviously, I'm a little lost here...

Comment: Your PHP file has an error.

Comment: undefined index: food in /foodstore/foodstore.php on line 6, 'Enter a food you idiot'     wow such debug

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh I figured it out.

I need to type into the browser:

localhost/foodstore/index.html

aka I need to type in the html file, not the PHP file...